# Custom TimerJobs are not showing under Job definition in SharePoint 2013 when activated the feature at web level

Tags: sharepoint-server, timer-jobs, feature-activation

I have custom Timer jobs solution deployed at site and web level scope.

When I activated the Site level scope features I am able to see the Custom Timer Jobs under Central Admin Job Definitions, but when activated the features at web level, custom Timer Jobs are not showing under Central Admin Job Definitions.

Please help on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Timer jobs can be only deployed only as the farm or web application level solutions. (although it can still point and work against specific sites)